# Get GeoLocation In The Browser

Tags: javascript, mobile, geolocation

I have the following JavaScript in my page to get the location of the user:

```
            state.currentTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, { enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 5000 });
```

It is intended that the page is called from the browser on a mobile phone. However the watchPosition method seems incredibly unreliable. Sometimes it won't ever get a location, other times the location is massively off, sometimes it will work fine and then just stop.

I have tried to eliminate the problem of the phones signal by testing it in a city with a good signal.

Is there a better way to get the location from a mobile while in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, that's the only way right now.  To ensure that you get more accurate results, you can check the `accuracy` property of the object passed to your `success` handler.

Comment: How do you ensure that the browser actually gets a location. Many a time I have waited for the browser on the mobile to load a location but does nothing until I refresh the page again. Is it worth creating a second timer that watches the first for a result and if no results is return clears the first timer and tries again?

Comment: I don't think so, it all depends on so much - satellite links are pretty hard to get :)  Try it though, set up a setTimeout or something and if you have no results, try again.

Answer (score 1):

I use :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(pos) {
        pos.coords.latitude;
        pos.coords.longitude;
        pos.coords.accuracy;
    },
    function(error) {
        error.code;
    }
);
```

All infos are here http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html